# Using functions and arguments in if statement in a bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to test the return value of multiple function calls while parsing an argument to one of them. I have tried the following but it does not work.

Can you help?

```
main() {
if prepareEnvironment "$1" &&
    buildInterfaceConfiguration &&
    applyNetworkInterfaceFiles
then
    echo ':D INSTALLATION COMPLETED :D'
    echo ''
else
    echo ''
    echo ':( INSTALLATION FAILED :('
    echo ''
fi
}

prepareEnvironment() {
echo '####################################################################################'
echo 'Preparing environment'
echo '####################################################################################'
echo "num arg: $#"
echo "arg: $1"
echo $1
...
```

This example just returns an error when trying to execute the functions.

Comment: Why not to use standard approach - assign return value to a variable, then use it in if clause?

Comment: Then I would have to either have 3 similar if-else statements or run all 3 methods before testing the result.

Comment: @UmkaDK yes, that was exactly the problem of the second problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First Answer

The subshell `$(...)` is the problem, just write

```
if prepareEnvironment "$1" &&
    buildInterfaceConfiguration &&
    applyNetworkInterfaceFiles
then
    ...
```

Assume `prepareEnvironment "$1"` would always print `some text`, then your version with `$(...)` would be equivalent to ...

```
if some text &&
    buildInterfaceConfiguration &&
    applyNetworkInterfaceFiles
then
    ...
```

... no matter the exit status of `prepareEnvironment "$1"`. In this case, `some` cannot be interpreted as a command by `bash`, hence the error.

## Second Answer

Regarding the missing argument:
I see that you called `prepareEnvironment "$1"` inside the function `main`. If you want to use the `$1`, you have to pass that to the `main` function first.

Comment: Somehow the arguments gets cleared when trying this. Before calling the function the argument holds the correct value but inside the function it is cleared. When calling these inside the function:     
    echo "num arg: $#",
    echo "arg: $1",
    echo $1I 
I get the following result:
    num arg: 1,
    arg: <empty>,
    <empty line>

Comment: @7heViking That's another problem. Please edit your question to show the source code of the function and specify which of the three functions is *the* function. Have you called the function as `f $1` or as `f "$1"`? Do you have any `set` commands in your script?

Comment: I have updated the source code sample now. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ah got it. I had forgotten to parse on the argument to the main() function.

Comment: @7heViking That's what I suspected. Glad you found out yourself :)